# Xamarin ListView selection help to navigate to new ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin

I am new to xamarin so still learning all its functionalities and limits. I am curious to know if you can redirect from the selection of a listview to another page containing a listview based on the foreign key. In this example the foreign key is CompanyID. Thanks!

Models:

```
 public class Company
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
 public class WellGroup
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    }
```

xaml:

```
 <ListView x:Name="CompaniesCollection"
                ItemsSource="{Binding CompaniesCollection}"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                ItemSelected="Companies_Selection">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:Company">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                        FontSize="Large"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: yes, use `Navigation` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the index to show the Company ID and Name according to the specific CompanyID.

**Page2: Show the CompanyID**

Xaml:

```
  <ListView x:Name="CompaniesCollection"
            ItemsSource="{Binding CompaniesCollection}"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            ItemSelected="Companies_Selection">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:WellGroup">
                            <Label Text="{Binding CompanyID}" 
                                    FontSize="Large"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
   public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
  
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       
        this.BindingContext = new WellGroupViewModel();
    }

    private async void Companies_Selection(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var index = e.SelectedItemIndex;
       
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page3(index));
    }
}
public class Company
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class WellGroup 
{
   public List<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
}
public class WellGroupViewModel
{
    public List<WellGroup> CompaniesCollection { get; set; }

    public WellGroupViewModel()
    {
        var C1 = new WellGroup();

        C1.Companies = new List<Company>() {
          new Company(){ ID=1, Name="A"},
            new Company(){ ID=1, Name="B"},
            new Company(){ ID=1, Name="C"},
            new Company(){ ID=1, Name="D"}
        };
     
        C1.CompanyID = 111;

        var C2 = new WellGroup();
        C2.Companies = new List<Company>()
        {
             new Company(){ ID=2, Name="A"},
            new Company(){ ID=2, Name="B"},
            new Company(){ ID=2, Name="C"},
            new Company(){ ID=2, Name="D"}
        } ;
        C2.CompanyID = 222;

        var C3 = new WellGroup();
        C3.Companies = new List<Company>()
        {
             new Company(){ ID=3, Name="A"},
            new Company(){ ID=3, Name="B"},
            new Company(){ ID=3, Name="C"},
            new Company(){ ID=3, Name="D"}
        };
        
        C3.CompanyID = 333;
        CompaniesCollection = new List<WellGroup> { C1, C2, C3 };


    }
}
```

**Page3: Show the ID, Name according to the CompanyID**

Xaml:

```
  <ListView x:Name="CompaniesCollection"
            ItemsSource="{Binding List}"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            HasUnevenRows="True">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <Label Text="{Binding ID}" 
                              
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
 public partial class Page3 : ContentPage
{
    private List<Company> _companies;
   public List<Company> List
    {
        get { return _companies; }
        set
        {
            _companies = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("List");
        }
    }

    public Page3(int index)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List = new List<Company>();
        List = ((new WellGroupViewModel()).CompaniesCollection[index]).Companies;
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```